# Clock replacement Policy

Tags: python, caching

My clock cache is not working. What I'm doing:

if key in self.items_to_index: set bit to 1, return the value from self.buffers.

if not:

call function on input to get newval.

call self._increment() until we see an entry in self.buffers with bit set to 0.

self.buffers[self._p] is now equal to [newval, 1]

Remove the dictionary entry with _p equal to that entry.

Then do self.items_to_index[k] = _p.

increment p.

My code for what's described above is: [not working]

```
def __getitem__(self, k):
    """
    Returns func(k) using the buffer to cache limited results.

    :param k: Value to be evaluated

    >>> clock = ClockMap(4, lambda x: x ** 2)
    >>> clock[4]
    16
    >>> clock[3]
    9
    >>> clock._p
    2
    """
    #when clock[index] is queried, this _getitem__ function is called
    if k in self.items_to_index:
        #hit
        index = self.items_to_index[k]
        entry = self.buffers[index]
        entry[1] = 1
        return entry[0]
    else:
        val = self.fn(k)
        while self.buffers[self._p][1] == 1:
            self.buffers[self._p][1] = 0
            self._increment()
        self.buffers[self._p] = [val, 1]

        for inputx, bufflocation in self.items_to_index.iteritems():
            if bufflocation == self._p:
                self.items_to_index.pop(inputx)
                self.items_to_index[k] = bufflocation
                break

        self._increment()
        return val
```

The entire class is attached her for reference:

```
class ClockMap:

def __init__(self, cacheSize, func):
    """
    Do not change existing variables.
    [Optional] You are free to add additional items and methods.
    """
    self.cacheSize = cacheSize #number of buffers
    self.fn = func #function whose results that you will be caching
    self._p = 0 # pointer
    self._increments = 0
    self._miss_count = 0
    self.buffers = [[None, 0] for x in range(cacheSize)] #actual output vals of the func passed in
    #hit: retrieve the value from the cache. Miss: reevaluate func with input, write to cache
    self.items_to_index = {} # dict,  input to buffer location, self.items_to_index[x] = buffer_index

def _increment(self):
    """
    Do not change this method.
    Updates the clock pointer. The modulo maintains the clock nature.
    """
    self._increments += 1
    self._p = (self._p + 1) % self.cacheSize
```

How I'm testing this and my test results:

```
def test3ClockMap(ClockMap):
check_dir()
clock = ClockMap(4, lambda x: x ** 2)
requests = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 1, 4, 7, 4, 7, 5, 4, 6]
with open(your_output + "task3ClockMap.txt", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["Request", "Result", "Pointer", "Increments"])
    for r in requests:
        writer.writerow([r, clock[r], clock._p, clock._increments])
diff_against_reference("task3ClockMap.txt", 3)
```

Diff file:

```
6,15c6,15
< 1,1,1,9
< 6,36,2,10
< 1,1,3,11
< 4,16,0,12
< 7,49,1,17
< 4,16,2,18
< 7,49,3,19
< 5,25,0,20
< 4,16,1,25
< 6,36,2,26
---
> 1,1,0,4
> 6,36,1,9
> 1,1,2,10
> 4,16,2,10
> 7,49,3,11
> 4,16,3,11
> 7,49,3,11
> 5,25,0,16
> 4,16,1,17
> 6,36,2,18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values are never added to the `self.items_to_index` dictionary, so values are never returned from cache. You can fix that by changing `ClockMap.__getitem__()` to handle the case that the current pointer is not in the index:

```
        for inputx, bufflocation in self.items_to_index.iteritems():
            if bufflocation == self._p:
                self.items_to_index.pop(inputx)
                self.items_to_index[k] = bufflocation
                break
        else:
            self.items_to_index[k] = self._p
```

Note the `else` block added to the `for` loop. This handles the case that the current pointer is not already in the index and adds it if so.

---

Your cache resembles a LRU cache. If you are using Python 3 you might want to check out the [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) decorator, e.g.

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def f(x):
    return x**3

>>> f.cache_info()
CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=0, maxsize=128, currsize=0)
>>> f(2)
8
>>> f.cache_info()
CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=1, maxsize=128, currsize=1)
>>> f(2)
8
>>> f.cache_info()
CacheInfo(hits=1, misses=1, maxsize=128, currsize=1)
```

Comment: This fixed my problem! Thanks. Can you explain how for....else works? I've never seen else used without if.

Comment: I see  : else suite is executed after the for, but only if the for terminates normally (not by a break)

Comment: @Jobs: That's right. basically the `else` clause is triggered if the loop terminates "naturally", i.e. it does not break. This is true if `items_to_index` is empty, or if the buffer pointer has not been used. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement.

Answer (score 1):

I believe its because of the line

```
for inputx, bufflocation in self.items_to_index.iteritems():
```

self.items_to_index is initialized to be empty and isn't updated outside of the above loop, so any code inside the loop would never run.

Comment: if not self.items_to_index:
                self.items_to_index[k] = self._p
            else:
                for inputx, bufflocation in self.items_to_index.iteritems():

Comment: Thanks. That was indeed the problem.